# Input/output error on specific files within a TrueCrypt container

Tags: linux, truecrypt, cifs

I have some files within a TrueCrypt container that I can no longer access.  IIRC, they were moved from another TrueCrypt container (FAT32) that resides on a USB memory stick (FAT32) to an NTFS based container on a remote network store.
They would have been moved from the FAT32 TC container on the USB to the network store, which was mounted with CIFS at the time.

When using an `ls -la` command on a specific directory in the container, I get the following:

```
ls: cannot access work/applicant.pdf: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/Guidelines.docx: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/doctor_letter_v1_300.tiff: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/Info_Physicians.pdf: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/intercultural experiences.docx: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/Medical Statement.docx: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/personal_statement_pointers.rtf: Input/output error
ls: cannot access work/personal_statement_v1.docx: Input/output error
total 4164
drwx------ 1 jimjamz jimjamz    4096 Jun 26  2016 .
drwx------ 1 jimjamz jimjamz    4096 Jan 30 22:07 ..
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? applicant.pdf
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? Guidelines.docx
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? doctor_letter_v1_300.tiff
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? Info_Physicians.pdf
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? intercultural experiences.docx
-rwx------ 1 jimjamz jimjamz    1077 Nov  1  2015 work.rtf
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? Medical Statement.docx
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? personal_statement_pointers.rtf
-????????? ? ?       ?             ?            ? personal_statement_v1.docx
-rwx------ 1 jimjamz jimjamz  114042 Nov 20 14:17 personal_statement_v2.docx
-rwx------ 1 jimjamz jimjamz   83859 Nov  5 17:50 proposed career.docx
-rwx------ 1 jimjamz jimjamz  500224 Jun 21  2016 Application Form
```

Similarly, I cannot access the directory at all within a graphical file manager (receiving the *Input/output error*).  However, I can copy those files that do have permissions, from this directory to another location.

I would do an `fsck`, but how can I do that on an unmounted TC volume?

I'm not sure whether the inaccessible files are corrupt or whether they just don't have any permissions at all, and these need to be set somehow.

Comment: This absolutely looks like file system corruption. First make a copy of the container, so that any attempts at repairing it doesn't end up making things worse to the only copy. Second forget about the fact that it's a TrueCrypt container, and just treat it like a loopback-backed file system. If the problem was somehow with the fact that it's a TrueCrypt container, you wouldn't get anything even remotely resembling that much valid-looking data out of it.

Comment: Do you suggest any methods on how I should attempt to repair it?

Comment: @aCVn - this was the best answer in regard to the problem I received.  If you care to provide your solution as an answer, I can mark and close it.